# Java Command Process Chain Generator

Tags: java, frameworks, command, chain

I have build a Java command line application which consists of several moduls. So when you start the application via the command line, you have to pass one parameter and its options like this for example:

```
cmd-> java -jar application -startModul1 option1 folderPath
```

OR

```
cmd-> java -jar application -startModul5 500 folderPath 1222
```

Currently I have to start each modul by starting the application and passing the requested parameter+options. For now thats finde but later, when I have lets say 20 modules, I want to generate a proccess chain with several moduls started one after the other.

For example at the end I could start both modules from the example above with just one command.

```
cmd-> java -jar application -startAllModules option1 500 folderPath 1222
```

Is there a framework, where I can generate such a proccess chain with existing command line modules? This should not be NOTHING programatically because I want to have some sort of xml-file or whatever, where I just configure a process chain and where I can select the modules and its parameters that should be run with one command.

Comment: You can use shell script to do this, I think.

Comment: Ok this could be a possibility but thats also some sort of programming. I want to encapsulate it so that the user of my programm just needs to edit a file or so. Of course this user knows the commands and its parameters but he should not change the source code and he should not write a script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought of turning your program into an interpreter?

Comment: Have you ever used a Linux shell? It's essentially an interpreter for a (very) small language that uses existing programs as primitives to generate on-the-fly pipe-based dataflow processing systems. No (traditional) programming needed, just commands with the odd pipe here and there.

Comment: In your case, you haven't described your workflow properly. Are the processes completely separate, or is there some kind of dataflow between them? Is that dataflow bytestream-based or object-based? Do the processes have inherent interdependencies?

Comment: Actually alle modules are completly independent. Of course, before starting some modules, some other modules have to be started before but that the user should know and thats not the problem. I can get some more examples. One module is importing data from xml files in a datebase, the next module extracts these data from the database to another xml structure and the third module compares the number and the quality of both xml structures. These three modules could be started right after each other. Some share the same parameter options and some modules differ in that way. Is that more clear now?

Comment: Sure. Instead of modules, I'm going to use the name Command (and look into the Command patters). Here's a suggestion: for each command, have a class that defines its metadata, meaning its name, the number of parameters, their types and so on. Tack on a class that represents a list of commands with their parameters, and can perform the actual execution. Now, you can write a parser that transforms a plain text file or an XML file into your internal representation, and it's executable. You just wrote a simple interpreter for your own DSL (Domain-Specific Language).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just do it now with a Windows batch file where I create the parameters, their options and a string with a whole process chain. Afterwars I try to start my jar with each of the parameters in the process chain string. I think this is a good idea but I just stuck with a looping problem. You can read these problems on the following two question-pages. Maybe you know how to solve it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12068698/count-var-in-windows-batch
and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072777/windows-batch-loop-though-variable-with-dynamic-token-count

Answer (score 1):

I think that parsing your command line, understanding what simple commands it must execute (from the xml you want to use) and launching them is enough.

How to launch them?

```
Process p = Runtime.exec(String[] cmdarray)
```

where cmdarray will have each of the words of the command:

```
{"java", "-jar", "application", "-startModul1", "option1", "folderPath"}
```

and

```
p.waitFor();
```

if you want this thread to wait until launched command ends.

**Update:** non concurrent

The later was in case you want to run several independent processes in parallel. One for command you need.

In case you only need to execute them **one after the another** there's a more simply way. When the main realizes it must execute multi modules, it calls itself with the appropiate arguments.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // parse params
    if (it's a multi module command line) {
       for (each module you have to execute) {
          main(new String[] {"-startModule1", ..., ...}); // call myself with different args
       }
    }
    else {
       // execute what you've been asked for
    }
}
```