# Windows Batch loop though variable with dynamic token count

Tags: windows, loops, dynamic, batch-file, token

In my Windows batch file I have some variable with a various number of strings.
For exapmle:

```
set string="-start" "-end someOption"
```

I count the numbers of a String the following way:

```
Set count=0
For %%j in (%string%) Do Set /A count+=1
echo.Total count: %count%
```

The output would be:

```
Total count: 2
```

Now I want to start an application as many times as I have Strings in my variable and I want to give the application the current string as parameter. I tried this:

```
 FOR /L %%H IN (1,1,%COUNT%) DO ( 

    echo %%H
        FOR /F "tokens=%%H " %%I IN ("%string%") Do (
            echo %%I
            rem java -jar app.jar %%I
        )
    )
```

But unfortunately this does not work: Thats the output:

> Number of current String: 1 "%H "" kann syntaktisch an dieser Stelle
>   nicht verarbeitet werden. (%H "" can not be used syntacticaly at this
>   place) Number of current String: 2 "%H "" kann syntaktisch an dieser
>   Stelle nicht verarbeitet werden.

How can I loop through the two Strings in my variable "string"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use a FOR-parameter nor a delayed expanded variable at the option field of `FOR/F`.
But you can create a function and use there percent expansion.

The splitting is an effect of the delim characters, it's per default space and tab, and they work also in the quoted parameter.
So I changed your delimiter to a semicolon, then it works.

```
set string="-start";"-end someOption" 
set count=0
For %%j in (%string%) Do Set /A count+=1
echo.Total count: %count%

FOR /L %%H IN (1,1,%COUNT%) DO ( 

    echo %%H
    call :myFunc %%H
)
exit /b
:myFunc
FOR /F "tokens=%1 delims=;" %%I IN ("%string%") Do (
  echo %%~I
  rem java -jar app.jar %%I
)
exit /b
```

Comment: Ok thank you very much. This idea help me a lot, but unfortunately it is still not perfect.
Because when I execute it, it says 
`1
"-start"
2
"-endt`
the first parameter "-start" is perfekt because I could use this parameter directly for my application but at the second parameter there are missing its options. The second parameter (so the second string) should be `-end someOption`

Comment: I don't understand what you try to say. Perhaps you could edit your question with some samples

Comment: Now I understand! I changed my answer, also to remove the surrouinding quotes

Answer (score 0):

Ok I will try to make it more clearly.

The answer above helped me just a bit.

As I showed at the beginning of my question I have the following variable:

```
set string="-start" "-end someOption"
```

I wanted to loop through this variable so that at the end I have two complete parameters:
first one:

```
"-start"
```

second one:

```
"-end someOption"
```

But after calling the function the echos are:

```
"-start"
```

(this is correct)
and

```
"-end
```

/this is wrong because he slits the string at the whitespace.

But at the end for starting my application I need two correct parameters. They should look like this:
first parameter:

```
-start
```

and second parameter with one option:

```
-end someoption
```

So I need to eliminate the quotation marks and the second paramert must not be splitted at the whitemark.