# Remove first and last character from a String in a Windows Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, character, strip

I have the following string inside my Windows batch file:

```
"-String"
```

The string also contains the twoe quotation marks at the beginning and at the end of the string, so as it is written above.

I want to strip the first and last characters so that I get the following string:

```
-String
```

I tried this:

```
set currentParameter="-String"
echo %currentParameter:~1,-1%
```

This prints out the string as it should be:

```
-String
```

But when I try to store the edited string like this, it fails:

```
set currentParameter="-String"
set currentParameter=%currentParameter:~1,-1%
echo %currentParameter%
```

Nothing gets printed out. What do I do wrong?

---

This really is strange. When I remove the characters like this it works:

```
set currentParameter="-String"
set currentParameter=%currentParameter:~1,-1%
echo %currentParameter%
```

it prints out:

```
-String
```

But actually my batch is a bit more complicated and there it does not work. I will show what I programmed:

```
@echo off

set string="-String","-String2"

Set count=0
For %%j in (%string%) Do Set /A count+=1


FOR /L %%H IN (1,1,%COUNT%) DO ( 

    echo .
        call :myFunc %%H
)
exit /b

:myFunc
FOR /F "tokens=%1 delims=," %%I IN ("%string%") Do (

    echo String WITHOUT stripping characters: %%I 
    set currentParameter=%%I
    set currentParameter=%currentParameter:~1,-1%

    echo String WITH stripping characters: %currentParameter% 

    echo .

)
exit /b   

:end
```

And the output is:

```
.
String WITHOUT stripping characters: "-String"
String WITH stripping characters:
.
.
String WITHOUT stripping characters: "-String2"
String WITH stripping characters: ~1,-1
.
```

But what i want is:

```
.
String WITHOUT stripping characters: "-String"
String WITH stripping characters: -String
.
.
String WITHOUT stripping characters: "-String2"
String WITH stripping characters: -String2
.
```

Comment: Your sample works (as expected), there must be another bug. Perhaps you tried this inside a block?

Comment: I get the following message:
`ECHO ist ausgeschaltet (OFF).
~1,-1`

Comment: Maybe thats because its in a function?
`:myFunc
FOR /F "tokens=%1 delims=," %%I IN ("%processChain1%") Do (


 set currentParameter=%%I
 set currentParameter=%currentParameter:~1,-1%
 echo %currentParameter%

  
   rem java -jar app.jar %%I
)
exit /b`

Comment: The cause is that percent expansion is at parse time of a block not at execution time. But in your case it can be solved with %%~I, [...dynamic token count](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12072907/463115)

Comment: Just this tiny little `~` did the job...awesome. Thank you very much

Answer (score 8):

Hope this will help you.

```
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    
    echo String WITHOUT stripping characters: %%I 
    set currentParameter=%%I
    set currentParameter=!currentParameter:~1,-1!
    echo String WITH stripping characters: !currentParameter!
```

Comment: You probably should have mentioned that this only works if *delayed expansion* has been enabled, which could produce some other hard-to-debug side effects.

Answer (score 4):

You are modyfing a variable inside a parenthesized block. Watch out - the new value will not be used within the same block (unless you delimit the variable with ! instead of % - and running in the enabledelayedexpansion mode).
Or just extract the couple of lines into another sub-function, using a plain sequence of lines insted of (  )

greets, Stach

Answer (score 4):

This script takes advantage of ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION.
If you don't know, batch scripts execute for and if commands all in one; hence if you do:

```
if true==true (
@echo off
set testvalue=123
echo %testvalue%
pause >NUL
)
```

You wont output anything, because when echo %testvalue% is executed, it has not recognized the testvalue has been changed.
Using delayedexapnsion allows the script to read that value as it is now, and forget the problem I stated before. You use it just like %testvalue%, but you may do !testvalue! to fix this:

```
if true==true (
@echo off
set testvalue=123
echo !testvalue!
pause >NUL
)
```

- Would echo 123.

---

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set string="-String","-String2"
Set count=0

For %%j in (%string%) Do Set /A count+=1

FOR /L %%H IN (1,1,%COUNT%) DO ( 
echo .
call :myFunc %%H
)

exit /b
:myFunc

FOR /F "tokens=%1 delims=," %%I IN ("%string%") Do (
echo String WITHOUT stripping characters: %%I 
set currentParameter=%%I
set currentParameter=!currentParameter:~1,-1!
echo String WITH stripping characters: !currentParameter! 
echo .
)

exit /b   
:end
```

---

~ Alex

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem but it solved by removing spaces between
Ex : set FileName=%Name:~0,11%  # Working as No space before and after '='
Ex : set FileName = %Name:~0,11%  # Not Working as space before OR after '='

So please try by remove spaces, It should work
Note: command line should be reopen to get refresh the background values else it shows the same output as it is stored in temp