# delims was unexpected at this time

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have this code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
chcp 65001
SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\leandro.batista\Desktop\SAMPLES RENAMER"
SET "destdir=C:\Users\leandro.batista\Desktop\SAMPLES RENAMER\BACKUP"
for %%a in ("%sourcedir%\*.pdf") do (
set filename=%sourcedir%\*.pdf
set cnt=0
set pos=0
PAUSE
for /f "usebackq tokens=%cnt% delims=_ " %%b in ("%%~na") do (
     COPY "%%a" "%destdir%" 
     MOVE "%%~fa" "%sourcedir%\%%b%%~xa"


    )
    )




:loop
if "!filename:~%pos%,1!"=="_" set /a cnt=%cnt%+1
set /a pos=%pos%+1
if not "!filename:~%pos%,1!"=="" goto loop

echo Count: %cnt%
```

The count code in :loop is to count all the underscores(_) in the file name so the count is stores in the variable %cnt% and then is inserted in the tokens because the underscores in the file names I receive are not certain.
The rest of the code is to rename the files based on the tokens and delimns but whenever I run this code it gives me this error : `"delims was unexpected at this time "`.
Can anyone explain me why ?

Comment: You are changing the value of `%cnt%` within the same loop in which you are also using it. Try this: `for /f "usebackq tokens=!cnt! delims=_ " `

Comment: I am facing the same error :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Batch loop though variable with dynamic token count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072777/windows-batch-loop-though-variable-with-dynamic-token-count)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just **guessing** you want to rename the pdf files to the last underscore delimited element of the bare name.
Using the `self expanding code`-technic of my answer to your last question this should do.

```
:: Q:\Test\2017\08\28\SO_45920139.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
chcp 65001 >NUL
Set "sourcedir=C:\Users\leandro.batista\Desktop\SAMPLES RENAMER"
Set "destdir=C:\Users\leandro.batista\Desktop\SAMPLES RENAMER\BACKUP"

For %%A in ("%sourcedir%\*_*.pdf") do (
    Call :SplitName NewName "%%~nA"
    COPY "%%A" "%destdir%" 
    MOVE "%%~fA" "%sourcedir%\!NewName!%%~xA"
)

Goto :Eof
:SplitName
set "Name=%~2"
Set i=1&set  "Name[!i!]=%Name:_="&Set /a i+=1&Set "Name[!i!]=%"
Set "%~1=!Name[%i%]!"
Goto :Eof
```

Simulated tree before

```
> tree C:\ /F
C:\
└───Users
    └───leandro.batista
        └───Desktop
            └───SAMPLES RENAMER
                │   one_two_three.pdf
                │   four_five_six.pdf
                │
                └───BACKUP
```

and after the batch is run

```
> tree C:\ /F
C:\
└───Users
    └───leandro.batista
        └───Desktop
            └───SAMPLES RENAMER
                │   six.pdf
                │   three.pdf
                │
                └───BACKUP
                        one_two_three.pdf
                        four_five_six.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem as displayed is caused by the initial value of `cnt` being `0`. You will receive this error if you attempt to use `tokens=0`.

It's not very clear what you expect this code to do. Perhaps it would be clearer if you provided some examples.